# “The ConnectionString property has not been initialized” error in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Every time I tried to connect to the database it give me this `error "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized"`

`How can i avoid this error and make it work?`

Here are my codes:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmLoginPage
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select*from tblPassword", con)
    da.Fill(dt)

    Dim newRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    With newRow
        If .Item("Username") = txtUsername.Text And .Item("Password") = txtPassword.Text Then frmMainMenu.ShowDialog() Else MsgBox("The username or password you entered was incorrect, please try again!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Information")
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You have instantiated an `OleDbConnection` object, but you haven't set the `connectionstring` property so it doesn't know where it should connect to. You also haven't opened it. Your code should look something like:

```
Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection()
myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString
myConnection.Open()
' execute queries, etc
myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Can you tell me where to put that in my coding, and how to make it fit properly, and also there bit that say "myconnectionString", it says "'myconnectionString' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level". What does that mean?

Comment: You already have the first line in your code. The rest can be put into your `Button1_Click` method (just rename `myConnection` to `con`). The `myConnectionString` is just a placeholder for your real connection string. For SQL Server this would be something like `"Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"`

Comment: @user2201924 - Does this solve your problem? If you need more assistance just ask. :)

Comment: For any others, I often, as a matter of habit, clean up using - 

    con.close(), then 
    con.dispose()
Bad habit if you want to re-open or re-use a connection (remember not to include the dispose command if you want to go back to that same connection)

Answer (score 1):

This Problem Occurs when you donot consider making a new connection
The solution is very simple, all you have to do is to make

```
Dim conString as string = "Your connection string here"

Dim con As new OleDbConnection
con.connectionSting= ConSting
con.open()
      'now simply write the query you want to be executed


'At the end write
con.close()
```

this will solve your problem.
if it doesn't solve your problem post reply I will try to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You never assigned your connection string to the connection object, just like the error is saying.

Insert a line setting the connection string before con.open.

Con.connectionstring = connection
Con.Open()
Or better yet, change your using statement as follows

Dim Connection As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=G:\VB Project\Library Catalog System\Library Catalog System\library.mdf;Integrated
Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"

Using Con As New SqlConnection(connection)